# CGRectIntersectsRect Logic - Is there a better/easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

Here's what I'm trying to do..

I have UIImageViews of all the letters of the alphabet. If the user pans a letter down from the alphabet to spell a word, and the letter panned and dropped, isn't intersecting any other letter, then I assume they're not spelling a word, so I add this letter to a temporary letter array.

Let's say they did this with 5 letters. And now they decide they want to build words using the 5 letters they've panned out.

How would I create an if condition that allows me to check to see if any of the panned letter pieces are intersecting with any of the letters that exist in the temporary array.

With what I'm trying to do, it seems can't just place my if statements inside an enumerating for loop. So I'm not sure what I can do.

Here is my pseudo code+ logic: http://pastie.org/2738238

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{

    //If a letter has never been panned or the currentPanned letter does not intersect with a letter that was added to the tempLetterArray
   //*letterintempLetterArray* = How do I test against all the letters in the array in the if condition?
    if ([tempLetterArray count] < 1 || !CGRectIntersectsRect(currentLetter.frame, *letterIntempLetterArray*.frame))
    {
        //Letters that may become words if other letter images are panned next to it.
        //Make the frame of letter larger so the frame intersects without having to overlap letter.
        currentLetter.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        currentLetter.frame = CGRectInset(currentLetter.frame, -10, -10);

        currentLetter.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [tempLetterArray addObject:currentLetter];  

    }

    //If a word hasn't been built yet, and user pans letter next to existing letter on the screen, build the first word.
    else if ([firstWordArray count] < 1 && CGRectIntersectsRect(currentLetter.frame, *letterIntempLetterArray*.frame))
    {

    //Align centers of the currentLetter and the *letterInTempWordArray* in which the currentLetter intersected with


        //Remove the letter from the temp array, and add it to the firstWordArray
        NSUInteger indexOfTempLetter = [tempLetterArray indexOfObject:*letterIntempLetterArray*];
        UIImageView *tempLetter = [[tempLetterArray objectAtIndex: indexOfTempLetter] retain];
        [tempLetterArray removeObjectAtIndex: indexOfTempLetter];
        [firstWordArray insertObject: tempLetter atIndex:0];
        [tempLetter release];

        //Make the frame of letter larger so the frame intersects without having to overlap letter.
        //Add the letter that was just dropped after
        currentLetter.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        currentLetter.frame = CGRectInset(currentLetter.frame, -10, -10);

        currentLetter.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [firstWordArray addObject: currentLetter];

    }

    //Start building the first word
    else if ([firstWordArray count] > 1 && CGRectIntersectsRect(currentLetter.frame, *letterInFirstWordArray*.frame))
    {
        //Align centers of the currentLetter and the *letterInFirstWordArray* in which the currentLetter intersected with
    //Do more stuff

    }

    //If the current letter intersects with a letter in temp letter array, and the first word array has already been built on
    //Start building the second word (Basically do this until 5 words have been created)
    else if ([firstWordArray count] > 1 && CGRectIntersectsRect(currentLetter.frame, *letterInTempLetterArray*.frame))
    {
    //Align centers of the currentLetter and the *letterInTempLetterArray* in which the currentLetter intersected with
    //Do more stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL touched = NO;

for(UIImageView* img in TemporedArrayOfLetter)
{
   touched = CGRectIntersectsRect(currentLetter.frame,img.frame);
   if(touched)break;
}
if(tapcount<1 && touched)
{
  foo code;
}
```

hope it help you.

Comment: I love you. This helped immensely. Thank you!